# How to add note in woocommerce table orders?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to add on the last column of the order list in woocommerce a private note text that is only for me.

I did with his code and now the last column is populated with the last note but how can I be able to add notes directly from the order table list in woo-commerce without clicking on order > adding note?

Is it any way to add a note to this column?

thanks a lot

````
 // WooCommerce - Add order notes column to orders list
 // 'Actions' to remain as last column
 // show only the last private note
 // Code goes in functions.php for your child theme
 // not tested in a PHP snippet plugin

 // Add column "Order Notes" on the orders page
 add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_order_notes_column' );
 function add_order_notes_column( $columns ) {
   $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
   unset( $new_columns['wc_actions'] );
   $new_columns['order_notes'] = 'Order Notes';
   $new_columns['wc_actions'] = 'Actions';
   return $new_columns;
 }

 add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'add_order_notes_column_style' );
 function add_order_notes_column_style() {
   $css = '.post-type-shop_order table.widefat.fixed { table-layout: auto; width: 100%; }';
   $css .= 'table.wp-list-table .column-order_notes { min-width: 280px; text-align: left; }';
   $css .= '.column-order_notes ul { margin: 0 0 0 18px; list-style-type: disc; }';
   $css .= '.order_customer_note { color: #ee0000; }'; // red
   $css .= '.order_private_note { color: #0000ee; }'; // blue
   wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles', $css );
 }

 // Add order notes to the "Order Notes" column
 add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_order_notes_content' );
 function add_order_notes_content( $column ) {
   if( $column != 'order_notes' ) return;      
   global $post, $the_order;
   if( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() != $post->ID ) {
     $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
   }    
   $args = array();
   $args['order_id'] = $the_order->get_id();
   $args['order_by'] = 'date_created';
   $args['order'] = 'DESC';
   $notes = wc_get_order_notes( $args );
   if( $notes ) {
     print '<ul>';
     foreach( $notes as $note ) {
       if( ! $note->customer_note ) {
         print '<li class="order_private_note">';
         $date = date( 'd/m/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) );
         print $date.' by '.$note->added_by.'<br>'.$note->content.'</li>';
         break;
       }
     }
     print '</ul>';
   }
 } // end function```
````